# how to access object from array that contains colon in it in php

Tags: php, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Accessing namespaced XML with SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991832/php-accessing-namespaced-xml-with-simplexml)

unable to access the object from this array after parsing

```
<abc>
<ls:location>
      <ls:address1>No 16 GLama</ls:address1>
      <ls:city>Kuala Lumpur</ls:city>
      <ls:zip>58200</ls:zip>
      <ls:latitude>3.092055</ls:latitude>
      <ls:longitude>101.684757</ls:longitude>
</ls:location>
</abc>
```

how to access to zip object

```
 $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $x->location->zip;
//"58200"
```

demo: http://codepad.org/FJDSM5su

Comment: @Natasha yeah, the xml you posted is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$content = '<abc>
            <ls:location>
                  <ls:address1>No 16 GLama</ls:address1>
                  <ls:city>Kuala Lumpur</ls:city>
                  <ls:zip>58200</ls:zip>
                  <ls:latitude>3.092055</ls:latitude>
                  <ls:longitude>101.684757</ls:longitude>
            </ls:location>
            </abc>';


$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

// accessing the wanted value in the object
// returns zip as an object
$zip = $x->location->zip;

// object to string type conversion
$zip = (string) $zip;

assert('$zip == "58200" /* Expected result: zip = 58200. */');
?>
```